# font-mappings.xml not overriding in DITA OT 3.6.0

Tags: pdf, apache-fop, dita, dita-ot

I created a plugin for generating PDFs with DITA OT. The plugin has its own font-mappings.xml file for the fonts we use in our documentation. Everything with it worked until we upgraded from DITA OT 3.2.1 to 3.6.0. Now, the font-mappings.xml file in the plugin is not overriding the one in org.dita.pdf2. The fonts in org.dita.pdf2/cfg/fo/font-mappings.xml are still being used. I double-checked the connections to the font-mappings.xml in my plugin, and I made sure I followed all the plugin migration tips. Any suggestions on where else to look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue already registered for it: https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/3688
I opened a pull request to fix it and if it gets accepted the fix will be available in the next DITA OT v3.6.1

Comment: Thanks, Radu. It sounds like the workaround is to modify font-mappings.xml in the org.dita.pdf2 plugin. I hope it is fixed soon.